# Is there any Generic Initial Context Factory ?

Tags: connection, factory, spring-jms

Hi I want to design a system where I am writing an application that connects to multiple JMS sources. I am using Spring JMS for this and when I create a connection factory I have to define the Initial_Context_Factory for that vendor and I have to have the dependency of the JAR in my project,

Example :

For ActiveMQ = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
    WebLogic = weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory

Required Solution: I want a solution where I do not need to add the dependencies of all the vendors. I need a generic InitialContextFactory that could be a parent of all the above mentioned ones.

Server JBOSS AS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `RefFSContextFactory` which uses a configuration file.

However, you can't get away without the vendor jars on the classpath because

a. You need each vendor's `ObjectFactory` which is used by JNDI to create the object(s)
b. You need the classes for those created object(s) so you can use the objects.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I will try the RefFsContextFactory